# Simplify with False assumptions gives wrong answers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

`Simplify` is very gullible: if it gets a `False` assumption, it'll believe anything is `True`:

```
Simplify[x > y, False]
(* Simplify::fas -- Simplify: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False. *)
(* True *)

Simplify[1 > 2, False]
(* Simplify::fas -- Simplify: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False. *)
(* True *)
```

This also holds for `$Assumptions` that turn out to be `False` (which is how I ran into this problem):

```
$Assumptions = {x > 0};
Simplify[1 > 2]
(* False *)

x = -1;
Simplify[1 > 2]
(* Simplify::fas -- Simplify: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False. *)
(* True *)
```

I'm sure there's a reason why this happens (and I'd be curious to hear it), but I find this behavior potentially misleading.  Is there a good way to work around this behavior, so that the warning message shows but `False` assumptions are ignored?

Comment: Most likely this  is based on logic fundamentals like de Morgan's laws.   E.g. `Implies[False, a]`  yields `True` and so the issue with `Simplify` turns out no longer to be misleading.

Comment: You get a warning message telling you this is GIGO. I don't see what more `Simplify` could do here. Wash your dishes?

Comment: The rule $(F \Rightarrow e) \mapsto T$, as inferred, is applied in `Simplify[e, False]` only if the expression $e$ (or its parts) is a traditional boolean-valued expression. Yes in `Simplify[x + y && x + y, False]` but not in `Simplify[x + y && x + y // Simplify, False]` (because the `e` here becomes simply `x + y`). An odd example: `Simplify[False + y, False]` becomes `True + y`, and two wrongs `Simplify[False + False, False]` make a double right (too true!). But these inputs seem nonsensical and of not much real practical importance.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think disregarding false assumptions (with a warning) would be better. The main issue is forgotten `$Assumptions`, not explicitly putting in nonsense :)

Comment: It is not possible to disregard false assumptions. If your assumptions are `{a<b,a>b}`, which do you discard?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Hmm, I guess a general solution is trickier than I thought. Luckily in my context, the problem will be single expressions that are `False` on their own, which are easily screened out.

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes. It may be true that this question arises from a misunderstanding, but it is far from obvious. I'm voting to keep this open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. Think `Simplify[q,p]` as $p⇒q$. You are evaluating the truth of *"$q$ under the premise $p$"*.

From a false premise, you can get either `True` or `False` implications. So $\left(False⇒q\right)$ is a `True` statement regardless of the value of $q$.

We can build a truth table

```
Column[
   Row[
      {
        "(",#2,"\[Implies]",#1, ") is ", 
        Simplify[#1,#2]
      }
   ]& @@@ Tuples[{True,False},2]
]
```

[image]

You get the `General::fas` warning.

> "This message is generated when the symbol False is encountered in a
> position where valid assumptions are expected."

You are been warned that you are starting from a false premise, but you get the expected truth table.

As [discussed in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61466793#61466793), you can see this on Wikipedia under [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators:%7E:text=%E2%86%92-,11,-p12) on column 11 (Credit to @CarlLange).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Artes for the comment explaining the reason.  I haven't tested these thoroughly, but as for a workaround:

```
Simplify[1 > 2, Assumptions -> DeleteCases[$Assumptions, False]]
(* False *)
```

seems to do the trick in the case of `False` `$Assumptions`.

```
SetOptions[Simplify, Assumptions :> DeleteCases[$Assumptions, False]]
```

could be a blanket solution, and

```
If[Cases[$Assumptions, False] != {}, Message[Simplify::fas]];
```

could provide the warning if desired.